# How to be notified about entering suspend mode?

Tags: android, sleep, notify, suspend

I'd like my application to be notified when system is about to suspend or sleep (before).
No matter to acquire a wake lock: i dont want to inhibit the procedure but only to be notified about it.
Thank you.
L.

Comment: the only way i found is to implement a BroadcastReceiver waiting for an ACTION_SCREEN_OFF intent but... i dont know... dont sound good to me.