# How can I listen in my android application when mobile change its mode to idle

Tags: android

I want to store the time when android mobile changes its mode from normal to idle state.
Is there any way to get this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to be notified about entering suspend mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668978/how-to-be-notified-about-entering-suspend-mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this out:

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/

shafali